# Can I change the value of a POST value without re-POSTing?

Tags: asp.net, httprequest

This is using ASP.NET 2.0 in an IIS 6 world.

I have a user submitting a form that sends the data to be via POST. The page receiving the data does some simple validations. If validation passes, then a black-box code routine runs that basically reads the data using Request.Form("NameHere").

I'd like to be able to change the value of the POST item and then put it back on the POST. I don't have the ability to modify the code that reads the Request.Form("NameHere"), so my work around idea is to modify the data during the page's load event. If I change the value of the POST item, then the black-box code doesn't have to be modified.

Is it possible to change the value of an item on the HTTP POST?

Has anyone done this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry everyone for not setting one as THE answer. My project has changed and I can't afford time to verify the solutions presented. I truly appreciate you taking time to help not only me, but the future people who search and find this question with answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even though it is a bit hacky, there is a way to change the value of a POST variable.

We can use Reflection to mark the `Request.Form` collection as non-readonly, change the value to what we want and mark it back as readonly again (so that other people cannot change values). Use the following function:

```
protected void SetFormValue(string key, string value)
{
  var collection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;

  // Get the "IsReadOnly" protected instance property.
  var propInfo = collection.GetType().GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

  // Mark the collection as NOT "IsReadOnly"
  propInfo.SetValue(collection, false, new object[] { });

  // Change the value of the key.
  collection[key] = value;

  // Mark the collection back as "IsReadOnly"     
  propInfo.SetValue(collection, true, new object[] { });
}
```

I have tested the code on my machine and it works fine. However, I cannot give any performance or portability guarantees.

Comment: I would not recommend changing form data as it super hacky :), but +1 as this is a good technique to know and can be used else where.

Comment: This has saved my bacon - I needed to insert into the QueryString to put a new front end of a method that is expecting a valid HttpResposne containing inputs as a QueryString.

Answer (score 2):

The current POST cannot be changed, however, you could create a new POST request and redirect to that.

Answer (score 1):

i see as the only way to change the original POST-destination to your own one and then in your code all requests that go to your address are dispatched to the black-box address.

there is some overhead through this though.

as far as i remember, the form-collection is unmodifiable, right? don't remember the exact structure but i think that

```
Request.Form("NameHere") = "newValue"
```

isn't going to work.

regards