# Is there a way to set HttpResponse?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, httprequest, httpresponse

I have the following code which I use to set HttpRequest querystring. I want to do the same for Request.Form.

I do this to hack some unit tests together. I want to do the same for Request.Form and I don't think I am interested in mocking at this point, looking for a hack.

Existing Querystring hack....

```
private string _queryString;
public string QueryString
{
    get { return _queryString; }
    set
    {
        _queryString = value;
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "http://tempuri.org", value), new HttpResponse(null));
    }
}
```

How can I do the same in setting Request.Form type values (with the option of retaining querystring too)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post contains the answer - 
[stackoverflow: Can I change the value of a POST value without re-POSTing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323130/can-i-change-the-value-of-a-post-value-without-re-posting)

```
protected void SetFormValue(string key, string value)
{
    var collection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;

    // Get the "IsReadOnly" protected instance property. 
    var propInfo = collection.GetType().GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    // Mark the collection as NOT "IsReadOnly" 
    propInfo.SetValue(collection, false, new object[] { });

    // Change the value of the key. 
    collection[key] = value;

    // Mark the collection back as "IsReadOnly" 
    propInfo.SetValue(collection, true, new object[] { });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `internal SwitchForm(NameValueCollection)` using Reflection and wrap it into an extension method:

```
public static void SetForm(this HttpRequest request, NameValueCollection collection)
{
    typeof(HttpRequest).GetMethod(
        "SwitchForm",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod
        ).Invoke(
            request ?? HttpContext.Current.Request,
            new[]
            {
                collection ?? new NameValueCollection { { "name", "value" } }
            });
}
```

Comment: that looks very good, however I am getting an error: System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection' cannot be converted to type 'System.Web.HttpValueCollection'

Comment: @Valamas: Yea, you're right. I took a look and found that `HttpValueCollection` is internal class so you will need additional actions to achieve the objective. I'll try to help to solve

Comment: not need to solve (see my other post below). Thank you for your help and you did help me look around to find the answer.

Comment: @Valamas: Glad to help. I learned something new as well. Don't forget to accept your own answer as correct. Or vote to close as duplicate. Your discretion